# controller:ctrlfmt Badly formed controller string ''. Must match `__name__ as __id__` or `__name__`

Tags: angularjs

In rootes.js

```
.state('main.mydata', {
    url: '/my-data',
    templateUrl: '/app/views/pages/my-data.html',
    controller: 'mydataCtrl'
})
```

Controller

```
.controller('mydataCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$http', function($scope, $state, $http) {
    console.log("Came to My Data")
}])
```

when i call the page getting error in console

```
Error: angular.js?bundleVirtualPath=~%2fbundles%2fangular:13708 [$controller:ctrlfmt] Badly formed controller string ''. Must match `__name__ as __id__` or `__name__`.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$controller/ctrlfmt?p0=
    at http://localhost:25282/Scripts/angular.js?bundleVirtualPath=%7eNaNbundles%fangular:68:12
    at $controller (http://localhost:25282/Scripts/angular.js?bundleVirtualPath=%7e%fbundles%fangular:10199:17)
    at setupControllers (http://localhost:25282/Scripts/angular.js?bundleVirtualPath=%7e%fbundles%fangular:9331:34)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:25282/Scripts/angular.js?bundleVirtualPath=%7e%fbundles%fangular:9116:32)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:25282/Scripts/angular.js?bundleVirtualPath=%7e%fbundles%fangular:8510:13)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:25282/Scripts/angular.js?bundleVirtualPath=%7e%fbundles%fangular:9210:24)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:25282/Scripts/angular.js?bundleVirtualPath=%7e%fbundles%fangular:8510:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:25282/Scripts/angular.js?bundleVirtualPath=%7e%fbundles%fangular:8513:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:25282/Scripts/angular.js?bundleVirtualPath=%7e%fbundles%fangular:8513:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:25282/Scripts/angular.js?bundleVirtualPath=%7e%fbundles%fangular:8390:30)
```

What may be the issue?

Comment: Please check out this doc.https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$controller/ctrlfmt

Comment: I've had this issue sometimes when using the 'controller as' method, and a mismatch in angular version

Comment: But it says badly controller string '', so it looks like you have an empty registered controller somewhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in page

> my-data.html

There was div with empty controller name

```
<div ng-controller="">
  ..
</div>
```

because of this it was showing

> Badly formed controller

Comment: After wasting hours on this error, sure humankind future in safe hands :)

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered the same problem when calling $mdDialog using angular-material. My issue was that the string referencing my controller had a rogue space at the end. Double check that the string value of your controller key in the .state function object doesn't have any spaces.

Hope this helps anyone else seeing this error as well.

Comment: div with empty controller name was there after removing that issue got cleared